# query data from database base on option value

Tags: php, html, mysql

i want to fetch data from database into HTML table base on below option value

```
  <form method="POST">
        <label>Status</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="selection_list">
                <option value="">All</option>
                <option value="A">A: Not Processed</option>
                <option value="B">B: Partially Processed</option>
                <option value="C">C: Completely Processed</option>
         </select>
         <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" value="Generate">
    </form>
```

if i select "All", php will select data from table where status = "All"
if i select "A: Not Processed", php will select data from table where status = "A"
...so on

how to writing code in HTML & PHP? please help....

Answer (score 0):

use an id to select field:

```
   <form method="POST">
            <label>Status</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="selection_list" id="list_id">
                    <option value="">All</option>
                    <option value="A">A: Not Processed</option>
                    <option value="B">B: Partially Processed</option>
                    <option value="C">C: Completely Processed</option>
             </select>
             <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" value="Generate">
        </form>
<?php 

    if($_POST['submit'])
    {
    $list_id=$_POST['list_id'];

    //write the select query you need to process with WHERE status=$list_id;


    }
?>
```

Comment: how php know which option that i select cause in "list_id" have may option. i want to run query one by one, mean that if i select "All" = 1 query, if i select A: Not Processed = 1 query

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty basic stuff.
Official already answered it, but instead of id, you'll have to use the name attribute.
Not to mention that there are security issues with this method.